# xslt - match ID's across two XML files

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two XML files:

```
<results count="3">
<result item="1">
    <result>
        <fielddefinition>
            <field name="COUNT" type="Unknown" columnDisplaySize="20" precision="19" scale="0" isCurrency="false" columnTypeName="INT8" columnClassName="java.lang.Long"/>
            <field name="TASK_ID" type="INTEGER" columnDisplaySize="11" precision="10" scale="0" isCurrency="false" columnTypeName="INT4" columnClassName="java.lang.Integer"/>
        </fielddefinition>
        <rowset>
            <row number="0">
                <field name="COUNT">17</field>
                <field name="TASK_ID">2364</field>
            </row>
        </rowset>
    </result>
</result>
<result item="2">
<result>
    <fielddefinition>
        <field name="COUNT" type="Unknown" columnDisplaySize="20" precision="19" scale="0" isCurrency="false" columnTypeName="INT8" columnClassName="java.lang.Long"/>
        <field name="TASK_ID" type="INTEGER" columnDisplaySize="11" precision="10" scale="0" isCurrency="false" columnTypeName="INT4" columnClassName="java.lang.Integer"/>
    </fielddefinition>
    <rowset>
        <row number="0">
            <field name="COUNT">1</field>
            <field name="TASK_ID">3140</field>
        </row>
    </rowset>
</result>
```

and

```
<result>
<fielddefinition>
    <field name="NAME" type="VARCHAR" columnDisplaySize="255" precision="255" scale="0" isCurrency="false" columnTypeName="VARCHAR" columnClassName="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ID" type="INTEGER" columnDisplaySize="11" precision="10" scale="0" isCurrency="false" columnTypeName="SERIAL" columnClassName="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="EFFECTIVE_FROM" type="DOUBLE" columnDisplaySize="25" precision="17" scale="17" isCurrency="false" columnTypeName="FLOAT8" columnClassName="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="STATUS" type="INTEGER" columnDisplaySize="11" precision="10" scale="0" isCurrency="false" columnTypeName="SERIAL" columnClassName="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="USERID" type="INTEGER" columnDisplaySize="11" precision="10" scale="0" isCurrency="false" columnTypeName="INT4" columnClassName="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="PRIORITY" type="INTEGER" columnDisplaySize="11" precision="10" scale="0" isCurrency="false" columnTypeName="INT4" columnClassName="java.lang.Integer"/>
</fielddefinition>
<rowset>
    <row number="0">
        <field name="NAME">qadasdasadsaaads een hele lange taak ff maken zodat ik kan zien hoe dat eruit ziet precies</field>
        <field name="ID">2364</field>
        <field name="EFFECTIVE_FROM">1513933257.97667289</field>
        <field name="STATUS">186</field>
        <field name="USERID">150</field>
        <field name="PRIORITY">0</field>
    </row>
    <row number="1">
        <field name="NAME">adads</field>
        <field name="ID">3140</field>
        <field name="EFFECTIVE_FROM">1513933432.78091598</field>
        <field name="STATUS">186</field>
        <field name="USERID">150</field>
        <field name="PRIORITY" null="true"></field>
    </row>
    <row number="2">
        <field name="NAME">dadsa</field>
        <field name="ID">3141</field>
        <field name="EFFECTIVE_FROM">1513933438.29942393</field>
        <field name="STATUS">186</field>
        <field name="USERID">150</field>
        <field name="PRIORITY" null="true"></field>
    </row>
</rowset>
```

One of these is input in the XSLT and one of these is a param in the XSLT. I wonder how I could group these two xml files on their task_id and id? I tried the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<xsl:param name="tasks_details"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <tasks>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/result/rowset/row"/>
    </tasks>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="row">
    <task>
        <name>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="field[@name='NAME']!=''">
                    <xsl:value-of select="field[@name='NAME']"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise> <xsl:value-of select="'-'"/> </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </name>
        <id><xsl:value-of select="field[@name='ID']"></xsl:value-of></id>
        <effective_from><xsl:value-of select="field[@name='EFFECTIVE_FROM']"></xsl:value-of></effective_from>
        <status><xsl:value-of select="field[@name='STATUS']"/></status>
        <user><xsl:value-of select="field[@name='USERID']"/></user>
        <priority><xsl:value-of select="field[@name='PRIORITY']"/></priority>
        <xsl:for-each select="$tasks_details/results/result/result/rowset/row">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="field[@name='TASK_ID'] = field[@name='ID'] and number(field[@name='count']) &gt; 1">
                    <created>true</created>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </task>
</xsl:template>
```

Not sure how I would connect/group these files together.. I need it to determine if a task is just created or if it has been moved around a couple times..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a minor correction required in the `<xsl:when>` condition inside the `<xsl:for-each>` used for the external file. Since the looping is being performed on the data of external file, the `field[@name='ID']` does not return any value as it is not present in the external file. It is present in the current file where the XSLT is applied.

You can store the value in a variable and then use for matching.

```
<xsl:variable name="ID" select="field[@name='ID']" />
```

Condition modified to

```
<xsl:when test="$ID = field[@name = 'TASK_ID'] and number(field[@name = 'COUNT']) &gt; 1">
```

Modified Template

```
<xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:variable name="ID" select="field[@name='ID']" />
    <task>
        <name>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="field[@name='NAME']!=''">
                    <xsl:value-of select="field[@name='NAME']" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="'-'" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </name>
        <id><xsl:value-of select="$ID" /></id>
        <effective_from><xsl:value-of select="field[@name='EFFECTIVE_FROM']" /></effective_from>
        <status><xsl:value-of select="field[@name='STATUS']" /></status>
        <user><xsl:value-of select="field[@name='USERID']" /></user>
        <priority><xsl:value-of select="field[@name='PRIORITY']" /></priority>
        <xsl:for-each select="$tasks_details/results/result/result/rowset/row">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$ID = field[@name = 'TASK_ID'] and number(field[@name = 'COUNT']) &gt; 1">
                    <created>true</created>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </task>
</xsl:template>
```

Output

```
<tasks>
    <task>
        <name>qadasdasadsaaads een hele lange taak ff maken zodat ik kan zien hoe dat eruit ziet precies</name>
        <id>2364</id>
        <effective_from>1513933257.97667289</effective_from>
        <status>186</status>
        <user>150</user>
        <priority>0</priority>
        <created>true</created>
    </task>
    <task>
        <name>adads</name>
        <id>3140</id>
        <effective_from>1513933432.78091598</effective_from>
        <status>186</status>
        <user>150</user>
        <priority />
    </task>
    <task>
        <name>dadsa</name>
        <id>3141</id>
        <effective_from>1513933438.29942393</effective_from>
        <status>186</status>
        <user>150</user>
        <priority />
    </task>
</tasks>
```

Comment: Well this seems logical, but I get this error on the for-each: Required item type of first operand of '/' is node(); supplied value has item type xs:string

Comment: How is the external XML being accessed? I have used the following to make this work -> `<xsl:param name="tasks_details" select="document('tasks_details.xml')" />`

Comment: Well this is being used within a framework, it's passed as a domdoc type as a parameter..

Comment: If you declare the types of your variables and parameters, you will get better error messages (you will also make your code more readable, and you may make it faster). You didn't make it clear whether `$tasks_details` is a document, or the URI of a document; or perhaps even the unparsed content of a document. Add an "as" attribute (and ideally a comment!) to make it clear what kind of value is expected.